# How to translate image after this rotation transformation

Tags: java, graphics2d

This code below is my paintComponent for painting image objects, but while I want to be able rotate the image with out moving it about the center but also translate it according to a certain value.

```
            trans.translate(xShift, yShift);
```

this is the line that I tried to use to translate my image, but it cuts off part of the image every time for some reason.

```
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (myImage != null) {
                AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
                trans.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
                trans.rotate(piece.getOrientation() * Math.PI / 2);
                trans.translate(-myImage.getWidth() / 2, -myImage.getHeight() / 2);
                trans.translate(xShift, yShift);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.drawImage(myImage, trans, null);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My sense is that java has a problem with compounding transforms.

Maybe you can find another approach: e.g. transform the image itself, then apply a simple translation:

```
    BufferedImage b22=new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)b22.getGraphics();
    AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
    trans.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
    trans.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
    trans.translate(-bim.getWidth() / 2, -bim.getHeight() / 2);
    g2.drawImage(bim, trans, null);
    AffineTransform trans2 = new AffineTransform();
    trans2.translate(xoffset, yoffset);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.drawImage(b22, trans2, null);
    // or just g2d.drawImage(b22, xoffset, yoffset, null);
```

Of course it will cut of if you translate a certain extend.